# Modifying SSH Agent for Public Key Signing

Tags: authentication, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to get SSH authentication to work without needing to store a private key in plaintext. I'm using an api that allows private key signing of a key stored in memory, and I'm wondering what's the best way to incorporate it into SSH. Since all I really need to do is supply a valid Private key signature to the SSH agent when it's doing its authentication, what would be the best way to do this. Can I just modify the ssh-agent a little bit to accept a signature I give it, or will I have to write my own agent to process this request?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ways to do that. Simplest would be to use PKCS#11 interface, which is available in `ssh-agent` and can be used for exactly this use case (provide signatures from safe place where the keys are stored -- generally Smartcard or HSM module).

Also encrypted keys using passphrase can solve your requirement against "storing private key in plaintext".

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to use the PKCS#11 interface, I'm not sure the device I'm using work well with it. To be more clear, I'm using an API that can generate an ECDSA certificate with the private key, with the key being inaccesible or readable. From what I understand of the SSH Authentication protocol, an ECDSA certificate is generated from the private key on the client side. So can I use the PKCS#11 interface to just give the SSH-agent my valid ECDSA certificate for authentication? Let me know if i'm not being very clear, thanks very much for any help you can give!

Comment: PKCS#11 is a standard so there is a lot of documentation about that. To get the idea how it can look like, it is a good start to have a look at [`soft-pkcs11`](https://github.com/kinnalru/soft-pkcs11/tree/master/example) project implementing this completely in software. You can most probably start from that and plug in your interface you are interested in.